# Wrong exit status upon evaluation of command substitution via ssh?

Tags: command-line, ssh, shell

I've the following simple shell command which I'm expecting to fail and it does on my local:

```
$ DIR=$(false) && echo ok || echo fail
fail
$ sh -c 'DIR=$(false) && echo ok || echo fail'
fail
```

But when I'm passing this command via ssh, it doesn't work as expected anymore:

```
$ ssh user@host sh -c 'DIR=$(false) && echo ok || echo fail'
ok
```

So I'm not quite sure where the problem is. I'm already using apostrophe, to avoid [too early variable expansion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300701/unable-to-run-a-sequence-of-commands-using-ssh).

What's going on and how to make the command substitution to work correctly based on the exit code returned from the variable assignment?

---

Another anomaly I've found with the following example:

```
$ ssh user@host sh -c 'echo 1; echo 2;'

2
```

which is printing only 2, instead of printing both 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that there are *three* shells involved:

1. the local shell which processes the `ssh` command;
2. the remote shell which `ssh` calls to process the command in the target host;
3. the additional shell invoked by the `sh -c` in the remote command.

The quotes do two things:

- they stop the local shell evaluating any variables in the local shell (1);
- they make sure there a single parameter for the remote `sh -c`.

Thus `ssh` sees four parameters: `user@host`, `sh`, `-c` and the required command. However, the quotes **are stripped** while building the fourth parameter and when the remote shell (2) receives its parameters it interprets the `$(false)` itself, and the completion code is set in its own environment before calling the subshell (3).

The additional shell (3) thus sees `DIR= && echo ok || echo fail` and `DIR=` is a perfectly valid, error-free command, hence the `ok` branch.

You can see the same effect in:

```
sh -c 'sh -c "DIR=$(false) && echo ok || echo not"'
```

or:

```
sh -c "sh -c 'DIR=$(false) && echo ok || echo not'"
```

In both cases it works "properly" if you put a `\` before the `$`, as this stops the second shell from expanding `$(false)`. I used double quotes to make the mechanisms clearer - if you prefer there is the rather tortuous:

```
sh -c 'sh -c '\''DIR=$(false) && echo ok || echo not'\'
```

Richard's example works, because all the expansion is done in the single remote shell, and an initial `false;` has no effect on the subsequent command. It has nothing to do with the topic discussed in his link.

Comment: Thanks, it works. See: [Enclosing  characters in single quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10989899/55075) for including a single quote within a single-quoted string explanation.

Comment: The new example in your edited post is exactly the same problem: the quotes get lost and the remote shell sees `sh -c echo 1; echo 2`. Only the first parameter `echo` is used in `sh -c`, which explains the extra new-line (the `1` is ignored as a superfluous parameter); and the semi-colon delimits the `sh` command, so that `echo 2` is executed by the remote shell, not the sub-shell. Because there is no parameter expansion, you can use both types of quote, so that `ssh user@host sh -c "'echo 1; echo 2;'"` will work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as expected:

```
ssh user@host 'DIR=$(false) && echo ok || echo fail'
```

It appears that when invoked as above the first statement in the shell pipeline will not work if it is a variable assignment.

Strangely, this also works as expected:

```
ssh user@host sh -c 'false; DIR=$(false) && echo ok || echo fail'
```

I'm not 100% sure what's happening here, but it may be related to this question: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126938/why-is-setting-a-variable-before-a-command-legal-in-bash